# Virtual directory settings in IIS 8

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

How to set the Application Pool for a Virtual directory in IIS 8 on a Windows 2012 server?

Answer (score 1):

Application pool can be set to an application and not to a Virtual Directory.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps will create an application pool named TestPool.

1. Open Internet Information Services Manager.

   - Click Start > All > Accessories > Run.
   - In the Open box, type inetmgr and click OK.
2. Expand .
3. Right-click Application Pools and select Add Application Pool.
4. Provide the required details on the Add Application Pool dialog box.

   - Name: TestPool
   - .NET Framework version: NET Framework< Version>.
   - Managed pipeline model: Integrated
   - Start application pool immediately: Checked

Answer (score 0):

You need to first convert your virtual directory to application first. For that right click on virtual directory then select "Convert to Application".
In Add Application dialog box, default application pool is shown here, if you want to change it you can change by clicking the Select button.
Select the pool required and save the changes made.